# jQuery isotope won't hide all filtered elemets on first load

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, filtering, jquery-isotope

I have a weird bug in Firefox, where jquery isotope won't hide all my elements, specified in the initial filter. Look [here](http://2013.brandpolice.de/projekte/) for my site

I could not find the problem.
Any clue or solution how to fix it?
All the items with class "entryItem" should be hidden by default, but they are not. This is the code I use. I tried onLayout, but it does not work on first load.

```
$container.isotope({
        animationEngine : isoengine,
        resizable: false,
        filter:':not(.entryItem)',
                    onLayout: function( $elems, instance ) {
                        jQuery('.isotope-hidden').css('opacity','0');    
                    },

        // disable normal resizing
        //transformsEnabled: false,
        // set columnWidth to a percentage of container width
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: getUnitWidth()
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is maybe an awkward solution, but I added sth like this to the initialisation of the plugin

```
onLayout: function( $elems, instance ) {
         jQuery('.isotope-hidden').css('opacity','0');
         setTimeout("jQuery('.isotope-hidden').css('opacity','0');",500);
      },
```

On Firefox there was an issue with hiding the elements, that is why i triy to hide it 2 times - the secont time after a slight delay resolved my problem